# Record a clicked link and then display the page name in a box as history

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I'm trying to record a clicked link and then display all of the clicked links in a box. I would like the box to display a small image of the page and name. Also, I would like to have the duration the user was on the page displayed below the image. The image in the box should be a clickable link to that page as well. Does anyone know if I should use HTTP cookies, or jquery?

The closest thing I found to what I was looking for is this: http://mtrpcic.github.io/pathjs/

(The only problem with that is it doesn't record clicked HTTP links.)

---

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

```
<img src="http://domain.com/image.png" onclick="save_data()" name="server" id="saveServer"/>
<div id='linkList'><script>
var links = [];
function saveLink(that){
    links[links.length] = that.element.src;
    document.getElementById('linkList').innerHTML += that.element.src+"<br>";
}
</script></div>


 <script> function saveData(){ var input = document.getElementById("saveServer"); localStorage.setItem("server", input.value); var storedValue = localStorage.getItem("server"); } 

 </script>
```

Is this right?

Answer (score 0):

To record the clicked links you have 3 options depending on your needs.

1. Call a javascript function on the onClick event with the link as a param and save the link into an array, then use it where you need.
2. Call a javascript function on the onClick event with the link as a param and save the link into the javascript local storage (google it if you don't know what it is). You will be able to show the links even if the client reboot the machine.
   (localstorage is saved in local datebases so with a bit of knowing a client can edit the entries, so this will be useful or not depending on your needs)
3. Call a javascript function on the onClick event with the link as a param and send an ajax request to save the link into a datebase. You need to have an accounts system, if you don't want to implement it, will be better the second option.

There is another option (which I personaly use). Using the localstorage and sincronizing to the datebase, that will made the load and save faster (if you do it well).

Example:

```
<script>
var links = [];
function saveLink(that){
    links[links.length] = that.element.src;
    document.getElementById('linkList').innerHTML += that.element.src+"<br>";
}
</script>
<img src="http://domain.com/image.png" onClick="saveLink(this);" />
<div id='linkList'></div>
```

Comment: Is this still the same with image links?

Comment: Yes, see the example I added to the answer.

Comment: So this code `<script>
var links = [];
function saveLink(that){
    links[links.length] = that.element.src;
}
</script>` Will display the link anywhere on the page?

Comment: I want to add the image and link to a box that is at the bottom of the page. Similar to grooveshark.

Comment: No, will only save it on an array. You have to update your box. Check again the example, I added how to made a list of the links into a div

Comment: The code I posted doesn't refresh the page. Why ajax? I think you don't undestand the uses of ajax, read about it.

Comment: My example will update a div, I don't know what type of box are you using. You have to edit my code to work with your box.

Comment: How long will that be stored in the box? Will it delete after going to another page or will it be stored in the box like a cookie?

Comment: I need it to be saved to localstorage then

Comment: Do it. Google about it.

Comment: If you want to know if your code is right, TEST IT. And no, your code won't work, but you are in the right track. Continue testing until you found your mistake. That's the best way to learn.